# How to sum column text file

Tags: php, sql, linux, file, text

Hello everyone and I immediately apologize, as 
I have seen various threads on the site, but unfortunately my knowledge is still insufficient to complete my project.
I have a text file and I have to do the sum of each column (just need the total):

```
1003|name1|1208.00|2.00&nbsp;&nbsp;|96.00&nbsp; |0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|98.00&nbsp; |90.95&nbsp; |7.05&nbsp; |8516.40
1011|name2|1450.00|2.00&nbsp;&nbsp;|49.00&nbsp; |0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|51.00&nbsp; |44.62&nbsp; |6.38&nbsp; |9243.7
1004|name3|1450.00|25.00|170.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|195.00|175.75|19.25|27912.5 <br>
1002|name4|765.00 &nbsp;|1.00&nbsp;&nbsp;|17.00&nbsp; |0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|18.00&nbsp; |15.13&nbsp; |2.87&nbsp; |2193.26
```

I need to get this(I have this file on linux then we can use Bash, PHP, Mysql... ):

```
1003|name1|1208.00|2.00&nbsp;&nbsp;|96.00&nbsp; |0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|98.00&nbsp; |90.95&nbsp; |7.05&nbsp; |8516.40
1011|name2|1450.00|2.00&nbsp;&nbsp;|49.00&nbsp; |0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|51.00&nbsp; |44.62&nbsp; |6.38&nbsp; |9243.7
1004|name3|1450.00|25.00|170.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|195.00|175.75|19.25|27912.5 <br>
1002|name4|765.00 &nbsp;|1.00&nbsp;&nbsp;|17.00&nbsp; |0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|18.00&nbsp; |15.13&nbsp; |2.87&nbsp; |2193.26 <br>
xxxx|Total&nbsp; |4873.00|30.00|332.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|362.00 |326.45|35.55|47865.86
```

Where xxxx  is the Id number (No sum here).

I've been trying to do this in PHP and MySQL -- No luck so far.

Comment: The spaces between the numbers are irregular. How do you plan to handle those?

Comment: Hi 
Each number is separated by "|"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
$file = '/path/to/your_file.txt';
if ( ($file = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $total = 0;
    $row_1 = 0;
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {

        // brutal dirt sanitization
        foreach ( $line as $k => $v ) {
           $line[$k] = (float) preg_replace('#[^0-9\.]#','', $v);
        }

        $total = $total + array_sum(array_slice($line, 2));
        $row_1 = $row_1 + array_sum(array_slice($line, 2, 1));
        //...
    }
    echo $total.' | '.$row_1; //...
}
else echo 'error ...';
```

also, you can sanitize each row by replacing array_sum() by array_map() wih a callback function

Comment: Thank you for your response :-)
but i get strange data :-(
i have it like :
nowy.txt 
3|1003|Deig|12"Deig|bakki|1208.00|2.00|96.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|98.00|90.95|7.05|8516.40
3|1011|Deig|12"Ponnupizza|bakki|1450.00|2.00|49.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|51.00|44.62|6.38|9243.75
3|1004|Deig|15"Deig|bakki|1450.00|25.00|170.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|195.00|175.75|19.25|27912.50
And i get Total like: 50851.65 | 0 | 39 | 39
I do it $row_x.. .... $line, 2, 2 ...2, 3 ... 2, 4 ...

Comment: maybe you have not sanitized cell content, you can try with my last edited version

Comment: Hi Thank You so much that You are spending time on me.
It is same as before- I do not even understand why there is such a result:  50851.65 | 0 
When I use your code on my file.
Can I somehow send you the file??-- maybe something missing in the file?

Comment: Hi Mkdgs.
You're geniuses!!! It Works!!! :-) 
I added the rest of the rows and it is ok now and that a large number on front is a Total of totals columns :-)
Thank you very very very much. You are my HERO :-)
P.S I am new to this forum and there is something(any points) which I can give You for Your help?

Answer (score 0):

Psuedocode:

```
open source file for reading
open destination file for writing
initialise totaling array to zero values
while not EOF
  read in line from file
  explode line into working array
  for x=2 ; x<14; x++ 
    add totalling array with floatval( working array )
    write line out to destination file
close read file
write out totals array to destination file
close destingation file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the text file data into an excel spreadsheet and then add up the columns.

You can use VB to get the text into excel and then continue adding up the values of each column.

Comment: he can just save as .csv  and make the seprator as `|` file why vb?

Comment: That should be done manually right?
importing the text and then changing the default delimiter.
I was thinking it would be nice if it can happen automatically and would be useful later for other calculations in future

Answer (score 0):

1) replace all | chars with , using str_replace
2) Use str_getcsv to create array out of the above resulting csv string
3) use foreach and loop through each row and calculate total

some PHP code

```
$str = file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
$str = str_replace('|', ',', $str);
$csv = str_getcsv($str);
$totals = array(0,0,0,0);
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    $totals[0] += trim($row[0]);
    $totals[1] += trim($row[2]);
    $totals[2] += trim($row[3]);
    $totals[3] += trim($row[4]);
}
```

the $totals array contains all totals!