# How to display data from text file in table? - Fixed

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have text file like:

```
3|1003|Deig|12" Deig|bakki|1208.00|2.00|96.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|98.00|90.95|7.05|8516.40
3|1011|Deig|12" Ponn|bakki|1450.00|2.00|49.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|51.00|44.62|6.38|9243.75
3|1004|Deig|15" Deig|bakki|1450.00|25.00|170.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|195.00|175.75|19.25|27912.50
```

How can I display the data in the table(it is possible??) each "|" separates the cells  and this text file can have 20+ rows.

Comment: Start by looking at the [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function; or at [SPLFileObject's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php) equivalent - the answers to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717581/how-to-sum-column-text-file-fixed) did half the work for you

Comment: As a quick and easy solution, looks like you should be able to just loop the rows replace the pipe with a "</td><td>" and wrap each row in a "<tr><td>" . lineWithRepplacement </td></tr> depends on the change of a pipe occuring IN the data

Comment: To be honest I do not know even where to start!! Can you give me some hints. I am able to display it on website but I have no idea how to accomplish this in a table. How to count lines in text file and add them to the table. Thx I will try to read a bit more about these commands :-)

Comment: @Shimpu: You sir, are in danger of becoming a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: I do not want to be Help Vampire -- Though I really like these creatures(Vampires) :-). But just starting adventure with programming and I really need some help to finish this project. BTW: Thank you all for such a quick reply and I'm taking up for testing :-) THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something simple like `explode()` to break each row into cells, and theme appropriately.

Sample code:

```
$rows = file();
print '<table>';
foreach($rows as $row) {
  print '<tr>';
  $cells = explode('|', $row);
  foreach($cells as $cell) {
    print '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
  }
  print '</tr>';
}
print '</table>';
```

Comment: Why use explode() and not read from the file as a separated-value file?

Comment: why not simply `echo '<tr><td>'.str_replace('|','</td><td>', $row).'</td></tr>';`

Comment: Thx hexblot -- exactly what I needed :-)
BTW: I am very impressed with your knowledge - realizes me how stupid I am in this field. Can you give me some sort of good books - good for beginning(just please do not yell at me-if it was a stupid question) Thanks again

Comment: @Christoph: because the above is easier to digest. Your solution is just as good though :)

Comment: @Shimpu: I'm afraid I cannot recommend any book since I've mostly learned on case by case, or from other developers. My formal education is in electronics :)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $array = explode('|', trim($line));
        foreach($array as $td) {
            echo '<td>'.$td.'</td>';
        }
    }
}
```